# What's wrong with my HOVER ON IMG

Tags: css, image, css-selectors, hover, web-inspector

I am desperate. 
Trying to implement a simple color change on an image on hover via css, I fail to find the proper way of using my selectors I think, but it's not exactly clear to me why it is not working. (i got it working for other pages on the site)
Here is what I have for the css :

```css
/* NO ROLLOVER > IMG is GRAY */

#post-1263 > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.vc_grid.vc_row.vc_pageable-wrapper.vc_hook_hover.owl-carousel.vc_grid-owl-theme.owl-loaded.owl-drag > div.owl-stage-outer.owl-height > div > div.owl-item.active > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.vc_grid-item-mini.vc_clearfix > div > div.vc_gitem-zone.vc_gitem-zone-a.vc_custom_1498264424124.img_holder > div > div > div > div > figure > div > img{
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}

/* ROLLOVER > IMG is NOT GRAY */

#post-1263 > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.vc_grid.vc_row.vc_pageable-wrapper.vc_hook_hover.owl-carousel.vc_grid-owl-theme.owl-loaded.owl-drag > div.owl-stage-outer.owl-height > div > div.owl-item.active > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.vc_grid-item-mini.vc_clearfix > div > div.vc_gitem-zone.vc_gitem-zone-a.vc_custom_1498264424124.img_holder > div > div > div > div > figure > div:hover img{
 filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: none;
}
```

I'm guessing something is wrong with the way I call my selector but I couldn't find another way to call it so far ( I actually am extracting the selector from the web inspector menu )

page is here : http://lesateliersvortex.com/

May someone help me debug this please ? I think I can't see straight on this one anymore ://

Comment: Your whole selector of hover is wrong. Can you provide with html, jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Martirosian what makes you think that the selector is wrong?

Comment: Because you have auto generated class names in your selector, which are most likely change on every page refresh

Comment: You should add class to last `div` in your selector and add hover styles by that class. try to avoid writing such long selectors

Comment: Thanks @Martirosian, but I can't add a name to this selector, it is provided as is, and I can't fiddle with the php.

Comment: @Martirosian classes are stable, not generated at page load but at page creation in the backoffice, so it should do.
look at page there http://lesateliersvortex.com

Comment: Any chance that someone look at the page and manage to find a way to write the desired css hover effect with this given selector ?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector are too long(visual composer classes are already unique) and there is another hover over the image that's why it's not working so add z-index , it's working

```
#post-1263 > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.vc_grid.vc_row.vc_pageable-wrapper.vc_hook_hover.owl-carousel.vc_grid-owl-theme.owl-loaded.owl-drag > div.owl-stage-outer.owl-height > div > div.owl-item.active > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.vc_grid-item-mini.vc_clearfix > div > div.vc_gitem-zone.vc_gitem-zone-a.vc_custom_1498264424124.img_holder:hover{filter: grayscale(0%);opacity: 1;-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);}

#post-1263 > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.vc_grid.vc_row.vc_pageable-wrapper.vc_hook_hover.owl-carousel.vc_grid-owl-theme.owl-loaded.owl-drag > div.owl-stage-outer.owl-height > div > div.owl-item.active > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.vc_grid-item-mini.vc_clearfix > div > div.vc_gitem-zone.vc_gitem-zone-a.vc_custom_1498264424124.img_holder{
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
z-index:9999999;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}
```